# getaddrinfo() vs NAPTR/SRV record

Tags: linux, dns

I have a doubt regarding Domain name resolution.We can do address resolution from DNS to ip-address format by using the function **getaddrinfo()** or by the procedure of NAPTR query,SRV record query and A/AAAA record.
1. Does the function use getaddrinfo() use the NAPTR query technique internally ? 
2. What is the advantage of using the function getaddrinfo() over the other procedure ?

Answer (score 10):

`getaddrinfo()` does not query **NAPTR** or **SRV** records, or indeed any type of record except **A** and **AAAA**. `getaddrinfo()` is an interface to libc's hostname resolution service which is modelled as a simple mapping between names and addresses. To see how this is the case, consider that this resolution service may consult `/etc/hosts` or, more rarely, NIS+, LDAP, relational databases, and so on, as per its configuration file `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. Notice how none of these NSS backends understand anything about **NAPTR** or **SRV** records.

Only DNS implements **NAPTR** and **SRV** records, and if you want to query them, you will have to use an API to query DNS directly (see `res_init()` and related functions, or more interesting third-party libraries like [c-ares](http://c-ares.haxx.se/) that support non-blocking operations). You can't use the libc hostname resolution service to do it.

As to your second question, the advantages of using `getaddrinfo()` are (1) it's a lot easier to use, and (2) you'll locate entries which users may have inserted into `/etc/hosts`, which you'll miss if you query DNS directly.

Comment: Thank  you  @Celada for the reply. I had one query from your reply. The first line of the reply mentions "getaddrinfo() does not query NAPTR or SRV records, or indeed any type of record except A and AAAA".Why is there a exception for A/AAAA record when it comes to querying hostnames ?Does getaddrinfo() query for A/AAAA records ?

Comment: There is no exception. libc's NSS DNS module queries for A and AAAA records.

Answer (score 1):

getaddrinfo gives back ipv6 address as well. Also you have option of providing hint.  There is one more variation getaddrinfo_a - this API provides results in async way. This is sometimes useful to avoid program getting blocked at one place.